# Java-API to generate empty requests and responses conforming to a given WSDL?

Tags: xml, web-services, jakarta-ee, wsdl, glassfish

What I need is a behavior, perhaps known to some of you from SoapUI:
You point it to a WSDL and it can generate default (or empty) requests and responses for each endpoint (method).

Is there some quasi-standard API (something from java.net ecosystem perhaps) which would achieve the described goal, sparing me from custom XmlSchema-or-WSDL madness?

*Note: I'm looking for an API, not a tool.*

### My attempt

I was trying around a bit but didn't came far:

#### Code

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.namespace.*;
import javax.xml.ws.*; // provided by Glassfish API in my case

public class App {

private static final String WSDL =
        "http://localhost:8080/myService?wsdl";
private static final String SERVICE_NAME =
        "{http://localhost/myService}myService";

public static void main(String[] args)
        throws Exception {
    Service s = Service.create(new URL(WSDL), QName.valueOf(SERVICE_NAME));
    Iterator<QName> portNames = s.getPorts();

    while (portNames.hasNext()) {
        QName portName = portNames.next();
        System.out.println("+ " + portName);
    }
}

}
```

#### Output

```
+ {http://localhost/myService}myServicePort
```

#### What now?

I have programmatically extracted port names.
But how could I extract endpoints / methods?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Apache wsdl2java plugin?  https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/eclipse/wsdl2java-plugin.html

Comment: Well, I wanted more something like an API, not a tool / plugin.

Comment: Something more like this?  https://ws.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#WSDL2JavaBuildingStubsSkeletonsAndDataTypesFromWSDL

Comment: Are you looking for something to help produce documentation, provide examples for developers, or are you creating smoke tests or maybe bootstrapping a set of functional tests?